# Calculating Marginal Densities for Three Variables

Tags: probability

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ be a continuous random vector with joint density 
$$
f_{(X,Y,Z)}(x,y,z) = 6e^{-x-y-z},\quad 0 < x < y < z.
$$

What is the marginal density of $X,Y$ and $Z$?

I have calculated $f_X(x)$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5B6e%5E%28-x-y-z%29,%7Bz,x,infinity%7D,%7By,x,z%7D%5D). 
I have calculated $f_Y(y)$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5B6e%5E%28-x-y-z%29,%7Bz,y,infinity%7D,%7Bx,0,y%7D%5D). 
I have calculated $f_Z(z)$ [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%5B6e%5E%28-x-y-z%29,%7By,0,z%7D,%7Bx,0,y%7D%5D).

Is this right?

Comment: What kind of comprehension do you try to achieve by plugging these into W|A? If your test is *Plug these into W|A and write down the result*, OK. Otherwise, I fail to see the point. (Strictly speaking, note that you *have calculated* nothing, W|A has.)

Comment: I'm using Wolfram Alpha because I'm not familiar with writing formatted mathematical notation. The computation is easy; I'm more concerned with whether I set up the boundaries of the integrals correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are correct, I suggest you integrate on your own(pencil and paper) since you will be doing so for your tests.

Comment: I did, but I posted the links to Wolfram because I am unfamiliar with writing mathematical notation on this site.